# Array key reference to a string?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to make a key name from a array a reference to a different variable.

Like this:

```
$keys = array('name' => 'abc');

$arr[&$keys['name']] = array();
```

But it doesn't work:(

is there any solution?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: because the name key may change, and I want the 2nd array to automatically change too

Comment: Associative indexes cannot be references. You will have to rethink your program design. Consider nesting arrays, like `$keys = array('name' => array('abc' => array()));`

Comment: While it won't be a straight-forward solution to your problem, you may consider looking into [SplObjectStorage](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php) as it may offer some clues. Since objects are implicitly passed around by reference, so it could get you moving in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the & away and ensure that $arr is set to an array before:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[$keys['name']] = array();
```

Answer (score 4):

**Associative (or numerical) indexes cannot be references.**

Just do:

```
$arr[$keys['name']] = array();
```

Answer (score 1):

Take off the reference:

```
$keys=array("name"=>"abc");

$arr=array();

$arr[$keys["name"]]=array();

var_dump($arr);
```

The output is:

```
array(1) {
  ["abc"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Comment: but if I change $keys['name']] the key name in $arr wont change.. this is why i wanted it to be a reference in the first place

Comment: You aren't changing `$keys["name"]`.  You still have `$keys["name"]==="abc";`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$arr = array("foo" => "bar", 12 => true);

echo $arr["foo"]; // bar
echo $arr[12];    // 1
?>
```

php.net/array !!! there is a text, befor u ask a question , it says that u shoult REALLY search befor u ask , the first ehtry in google , the first ehtry on php.net <- the very first place to look 4 php cuestions

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the key of an array element using a reference, as you want.

You need to create a new one, and unset the previous:

```
$key = 'abc';
$array[$key] = 'value';

// to change the key:
$new_key = 'def';
$array[$new_key] = $array[$key];
unset($array[$key]);
```

You wanted something like the code below, but it does not exist nothing like that in PHP:

```
$key = 'abc';
$array[&$key] = 'value'; // this is not legal in PHP
$key = 'def'; // (this was supposed to change the key)
```